# Swift index 0 beyond bounds for empty array in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to populate tableview with parse with 2 labels connected to the the main tv controller with PFTableViewCell

when I add the (numberOfSectionsInTableView + numberOfRowsInSection ) the app crash

but when I deleted it it works but it show nothing.

[image]
[image]

This the table view cell

```
class courseCell: PFTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var location: UILabel!

}
```

This the table view controller

```
class courseTVC: PFQueryTableViewController {


override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}


required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)



    self.parseClassName = "courses"
    self.textKey = "Location"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false

}
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "courses")
    query.orderByDescending("Location")
    return query
}


  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell" , forIndexPath : indexPath) as? courseCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = courseCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


    cell!.name.text = object["Price"] as! String!
    cell!.location.text = object["Location"] as! String!




    return cell!
}
```

[image: debugging message]

I don't know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `PFQueryTableViewController`, https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html it looks like you shouldn't be overriding those two methods.

`– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:` should be called already for all the rows in your table based on your `objects`. You shouldn't override `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` because the Parse controller handles all of that for you. You are overriding these methods and hardcoding a number which causes Parse to try to fetch and object for a row that is out of bounds (it doesn't exist). It looks like there are actually no objects in your datasource.

Comment: Yes I did it first time I skipped those two methods"delete" but the view controller views nothings and if you can see the two image of Parse's objects +empty table view fetching nothing form parse's datasource"core"

Comment: There are two labels connected to the PFTableViewCell

Comment: Got it the issue was your answer + class should be capital latter :)

Comment: @JamesMoriarty Can you post a screen shot of your fix? I had this issue with PFTableView and now I'm having it again with PFCollectionViewController. Can't remember how I fixed it.