# Only 1 Section Showing PFQueryCollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I'm pulling images off of Parse and loading them into a `PFQueryCollectionViewController`. The query runs and the images are pulled. However it is only returning one row of images instead of multiple rows of images. There are plenty of images. I've been stuck on this one for awhile, it's driving me crazy.

If I set up the basic `override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`  and `override func numberOfItemsInCollectionView` methods it returns an error upon loading the view that says `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`

Again, one row of images does appear but it does not continue to a second row.

```
class MasterCollection: PFQueryCollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet var cView: UICollectionView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.objectsPerPage = 77

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    cView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cView!.dataSource = self
    cView!.delegate = self
    self.cView!.registerClass(MasterCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    cView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(cView!)!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

 /*override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 100

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}*/

override func queryForCollection() -> PFQuery {
    println("query ran")

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: questionClass)
    if (objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    }
    query.orderByAscending(objectId)

    println(query)
    return query
}

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {

    let cell: MasterCollectionCell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterCollectionCell

    cell.parseObject = object

    if let pfObject = object {

        let image = pfObject[questionImage] as? PFFile
        cell.collectionCellImageView?.file = image
        cell.collectionCellImageView?.loadInBackground()
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image]

This is similar to my problem but I'm not working with TableView: [Swift index 0 beyond bounds for empty array in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200418/swift-index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array-in-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in trying to override the layout settings that are implemented on Storyboard. Instead of programmatically setting the specifications for layout and cell properties in the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` most constant properties are set in Attributes Inspector.

Of course this follows the rule that 9 times out of 10 it's something simpler than you're trying to make it.